# Need to Select all Cells in the WorkBOOK to replace all "=" with "####"

Tags: excel, replace, cells, formulas

I need the Excel VBA code for selecting all cells in my workBOOK (not sheet). There are plenty of Sheets("Name").Cells but i dont see a simple way of all cells across the workbook. I need to replace all "=" in cells across the workbook with "####". Thanks for all the help

Comment: Why VBA? Why not inbuilt Find And Replace?

Answer (score 2):

**VBA solution**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceAllValues()

    Dim TheSheet        As Worksheet
    Dim MatchCase       As Boolean


    For Each TheSheet In Worksheets
        TheSheet.Cells.Replace _
            What:="=", _
            Replacement:="####", _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            MatchCase:=False
    Next

End Sub
```

- Alt + F11 opens the VB editor
- Menu Insert -> Module
- Enter your code
- Save the code (macro-enabled excel)
- Push F5 (or menu Run -> Run Sub/Userform)

**Built-in replace solution**

And if you want to use the built-in find-and-replace:
[image]

> if you have e.g. *=a1+b1* and you want to replace even this to ####a1+b1 then remember to have the "Match entire cell contents" unchecked.